# How to make the span text not to be pushed to next line based on the preceding span element content using css?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

i want to keep the span elements text fixed to two lines in a flexbox.

What i am trying to do?

[image]

I want to implement something like above.
The problem is when the value in /400 becomes single digit, two digit or whatever the length is the text "Available some value" and "Available some value 2" wraps to three lines. i want it to be always in two lines...

like below

```
Available   Available
some value  some value2
```

How can i keep it constant always wrapped in two lines.

below is my code,

```
<Wrapper>
    <Container>
        <Comp size={12} weight={700}>
            Name
         </Comp>
         <Text size={12}>
             Nameeee Nameeeee Nameee
         </Text>
     </Container>
     <View>
        <Text size={25} weight={700}>
            3
        </Text>
        <Text size={14} weight={700}>
            /400
        </Text>
    </View>
    <firstText size={12}>
        Available some value
    </firstText>
    <Divider />
    <View>
        <Text size={25} weight={700}>
            2
        </Text>
        <Text size={14} weight={700}>
            /400
        </Text>
    </View>
    <secondText size={12}>
        Available some value2
    </secondText>
</Wrapper>


const Wrapper = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 32px;
    padding: 12px 16px;
`;

 const Container = styled.div`
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     white-space: nowrap;
`;

 const View = styled.div`
     display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: baseline;
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin-left: 16px;
    margin-top: 8px;
`;

 const firstText = styled(Text)`
     margin-left: 8px;
     width: 88px;
 `;

  const secondText = styled(Text)`
      margin-left: 8px;
  `;

   const Divider = styled.div`
       height: 37px;
       margin-left: 16px;
       border: 1px solid red;
   `;
```

How can i fix this. could someone help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: What if two lines doesn't fit, do you want it to overflow?

Comment: first line should always have only Available and next line rest of the text.

Comment: @someuser2491 Can't you use a `<br />` tag?

Comment: If you wrap "some value" in a non-breaking span you could manage that...with `white-space:nowrap!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For breaking the text in a certain part, add a `<br />` line break and that's what they're used for.

In case, if you want a text not break apart, use the following CSS, but make sure you wrap it inside a span or something.

```css
span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

In your case, if I understand correctly, you want this:

- Totally, always two lines.
- Available should be in its own line.
- Whatever the value, the next line should be in one single line.

Here's my proposal:

```js
<secondText size={12}>
    <div className="status">Available</div>
    <div className="value">some value2</div>
</secondText>
```

And for the CSS part:

```css
.value {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Also I noticed something. If `secondText` is a custom React component, make sure it starts with an uppercase. Like `SecondText`.

Hope the explanation is better. I have used `<div>` as the line break here is **presentational** and not a content.

Comment: Thanks. is there a way i can do this something automatically with flexbox rather than splitting the text to seperate elements

Comment: @someuser2491 No, you can't use flexbox, coz it expects each element to be in its own container.